# Azure Media Player Ad overlay

Tags: azure-media-services

I am using Azure Media Player and loading an ad from a VAST xml file. Everything works well, the ad plays fine, but in this case I don't want to show that "Ad 8 seconds" countdown at the top. Is there a way to turn this off in Azure Media Player?

[image: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p1brbc6ugvkotfv/Screenshot%202019-01-18%2014.52.58.png?dl=0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your pages root CSS stylesheet. I'm checking to see if there is an actual option for this in the setup

```
.amp-content-title-ad .description{
  display: none ;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!